# Multi Staging Docker Image for production use

Tags: docker, go

I have a multi staging golang image that I want to use for production and development the docker file is something like this

```
FROM  golang:1.16 AS Development


RUN mkdir /project
ADD . /project
WORKDIR /project

RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build  -o main ./...

FROM scratch AS production
COPY --from=development /project .
CMD ["./main"]
```

when i build with docker

docker build -t myApp .

and run docker images -> i see the 2 images created
are there an option to provide docker to create only the second image or the first image ?

Comment: Every step creates an image, but not every image is named. What is the problem with the above? Also, there's one possible solution which is obvious when you look at the `docker build` docs.

Comment: I want to build with --target production ,but only the second image will be created ,are there an option to do that?

Comment: With multi-stage builds, you use multiple FROM statements in your Dockerfile. Each FROM instruction can use a different base, and each of them begins a new stage of the build. You can selectively copy artifacts from one stage to another, leaving behind everything you don’t want in the final image. So the final image will be the output image from the docker file